# Nuxt - props error : Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm having this error:

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

in this line:

```
<script>

    export default {
        props: {
            items: {
            type: {Array, Object},
            default: [],
            },
        }        
    }
</script>
```

the error is in `type: {Array, Object}`
what can I do ??

Answer (score 1):

The prop type should be an array if you've multiple types, and the default value should be a function that returns an array :

```
  export default {
        props: {
            items: {
            type: [Array, Object],
            default:()=> [],
            },
        }        
    }
```